# Is there any way to have Emacs save your undo history between sessions?

Tags: emacs

Is there any way to have EMACS save your undo history between sessions?

I'm aware of the savehist lib, the saveplace lib, the desktop lib, and the windows lib, these all provide some session control but none seem to save the undo history.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some code I wrote which seems to do the trick.  It isn't bullet-proof, as in, it doesn't handle all the file handling intricacies that Emacs does (e.g. overriding where auto-save files are put, symlink handling, etc.).  But, it seemed to do the trick for some simple text files I manipulated.

```
(defun save-undo-filename (orig-name)
  "given a filename return the file name in which to save the undo list"
  (concat (file-name-directory orig-name)
          "."
          (file-name-nondirectory orig-name)
          ".undo"))

(defun save-undo-list ()
  "Save the undo list to a file"
  (save-excursion
    (ignore-errors
      (let ((undo-to-save `(setq buffer-undo-list ',buffer-undo-list))
            (undo-file-name (save-undo-filename (buffer-file-name))))
        (find-file undo-file-name)
        (erase-buffer)
        (let (print-level
              print-length)
          (print undo-to-save (current-buffer)))
        (let ((write-file-hooks (remove 'save-undo-list write-file-hooks)))
          (save-buffer))
        (kill-buffer))))
  nil)

(defvar handling-undo-saving nil)

(defun load-undo-list ()
  "load the undo list if appropriate"
  (ignore-errors
    (when (and
           (not handling-undo-saving)
           (null buffer-undo-list)
           (file-exists-p (save-undo-filename (buffer-file-name))))
      (let* ((handling-undo-saving t)
             (undo-buffer-to-eval (find-file-noselect (save-undo-filename (buffer-file-name)))))
        (eval (read undo-buffer-to-eval))))))

(add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'save-undo-list)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'load-undo-list)
```

Comment: nice man, this looks great, I use undo-tree so it's not working out of the box for me, but i bet i can get this to work with undo-tree

Comment: @openist It looks like you could simply check for `buffer-undo-tree` and save that the same way as the code saves `buffer-undo-list`.

Comment: Indeed, that's what i assumed as well, unfortunately though I'm still not able to get it to work with undo-tree mode disabled. I'm still working on debugging it, I'm pretty new to ELISP, but when I load up a file the undo history is not available.  The hooks are being called, but I'm not sure where it's falling apart for me.

Comment: @openist Did you fix this for undo-tree?

Comment: Can the `.undo` files save under the `~/.emacs.d` folder? @TreyJackson

Answer (score 23):

From version 0.4 onwards, undo-tree supports persistent storage of undo-tree data between sessions "out of the box". (Note that there are significant bug-fixes related to this feature in more recent versions; the latest version at the time of writing is 0.6.3.)

Simply enable the `undo-tree-auto-save-history` customization option to automatically save and load undo history in undo-tree buffers. Or use the `undo-tree-save/load-history` commands to save and load undo history manually.

You need at least Emacs version 24.3 for this to work reliably, but with a recent enough Emacs it works very well.

Comment: Except there doesn't seem to be a way to make it save the undo history somewhere other than in the same directory as the file you are editing.

Comment: Just override the `undo-tree-make-history-save-file-name' function in your .emacs, in exactly the same way as you would override `make-auto-save-file-name'.

Comment: For auto save I just override auto-save-list-file-prefix and auto-save-file-name-transforms.

Comment: Override `undo-tree-make-history-save-file-name` to call `make-auto-save-file-name` and then append an additional suffix specific to undo-tree. Then it will just use the same directory as your autosaves.

Comment: In recent versions of undo-tree, you can also customize `undo-tree-history-directory-alist' (cf. `backup-directory-alist).

Answer (score 21):

Add the following to your .emacs file :

```
(global-undo-tree-mode)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
```

## Explanation

- `(global-undo-tree-mode)` enables undo tree.
- `(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)` enables auto save of undo history.
- `(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))` so that your project does not get littered with undo-history savefiles.

---

`undo-fu-session` is another great alternative as mentioned [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75674105/2724649). This will also ensure that we avoid changing how undos work by introducing undo-tree.

Comment: I am having `assignment to free variable ‘undo-tree-auto-save-history’` ,would it be a problem?

Comment: It saves into give folder path but does not re-read from there when emacs daemon is restarted

Comment: This solution looks appealing but I've got the following error: *Symbol's function definition is void : global-undo-tree-mode* when trying this code.

Comment: You might have to install it from [elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html) @Konrad

Comment: While undo-tree supports saving/restoring, it requires using undo-tree (which is an alternative system for undo), personally I ran into undo corruption and rather avoid it (`undo-fu-session` is an alternative, noted in another answer).

Answer (score 8):

desktop-save-mode does not save buffer-undo-list by default. You just have to tell him!

```
(add-to-list 'desktop-locals-to-save 'buffer-undo-list)
```

Comment: The above answer (in and of itself) is insufficient when using a current version of Emacs Trunk because the `buffer-undo-list` is excluded from the function `(buffer-local-variables)` -- the link to the following thread discusses a workaround that `push`-es the `buffer-undo-list` to `ll` towards the tail end of the function `desktop-buffer-info` -- it goes just after the last `dolist` section and before the final `ll` is thrown as the result.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3725/2287 -- i.e., `(push (cons 'buffer-undo-list buffer-undo-list) ll)`

Comment: What is this variable `ll`? To which list should this be pushed? Seems this still doesn't work, would really like to be able to save the buffer-undo-list. Thanks

Comment: Ok, never mind, I found it inside the `desktop.el.gz` file, it is inside the function `desktop-buffer-info`.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs Session](http://emacs-session.sourceforge.net/index.html) appears to support this:

```
(add-to-list 'session-locals-include 'buffer-undo-list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get the undo history working by using the information provided here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3725/2287

Instead of patching the original file `desktop.el.gz` I created an advice that temporarily overrides `(buffer-local-variables)` then I use it together with the function that gathers information about the buffer.

```
(defun +append-buffer-undo-list-to-buffer-local-variables-advice (orig-fn &rest args)
  "Override `buffer-local-variables' and call ORIG-FN with ARGS.
There is a bug in Emacs where the `buffer-undo-list' data is
missing from the output of `buffer-local-variables'. This
advice temporarily overrides the function and appends the
missing data."
  (let ((orig-buffer-local-variables-fn (symbol-function 'buffer-local-variables)))
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'buffer-local-variables)
               #'(lambda () (append (funcall orig-buffer-local-variables-fn)
                               `(,(cons 'buffer-undo-list buffer-undo-list))))))
      (apply orig-fn args))))

(advice-add #'desktop-buffer-info :around #'+append-buffer-undo-list-to-buffer-local-variables-advice)
(push 'buffer-undo-list desktop-locals-to-save)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Can default answer could be `y` for `Save desktop? (y or n)`?  and its default path

Answer (score 1):

You can use Undo Fu Session

> This package writes undo/redo information upon file save which is restored where possible when the file is loaded again.

After installing the package just add `(undo-fu-session-global-mode)` to you init file to enable it.

See https://codeberg.org/ideasman42/emacs-undo-fu-session for more information.