# Persistent Undos in Emacs

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to have Emacs save your undo history between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985050/is-there-any-way-to-have-emacs-save-your-undo-history-between-sessions)

Could someone please tell me how I can get persistent undos in Emacs (just like in vim)? By persistent undos, I mean the ability to visit a file later and undo actions from an earlier visit.

Note: This [web page describes persistent undos in vim](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19548).